# How do I remove my image from images folder in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, image, unlink

In my edit detail page there is an image field, I want that when i upload new image old photo will remove from images folder and new photo will upload and if i do not upload pic than during submit no error will generate

here is my image upload code

```
$file = $request->file('file');
$name = time() . $file->getClientOriginalName();
$file->move('uploads/images', $name);
$employee->file = $name;
$employee->save();
```

How can I unlink it?

Comment: `@unlink( $_SERVER[ 'DOCUMENT_ROOT' ].'uploads/images'.( $employee->file ) );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you’re updating a model, you can delete the old file and upload the new one if one is provided:

```
if ($request->hasFile('file')) {
    Storage::delete($employee->file); // If $file is path to old image

    $employee->file = $request->file('file')->store('name-of-folder');
}
```

Comment: It's a good practice to check and see if the file exists and then delete it: Storage::exists($employee->file)

Comment: I got this error
***Non-static method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::delete() should not be called statically***

Comment: @John_rees Because you don’t call the `delete()` method on the model, you call it on the `Storage` facade: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/filesystem#deleting-files

Comment: @RouhollahMazarei `Storage::delete()` checks if the file exists and just returns `false` if it doesn’t, so you can safely use it.

Answer (score -1):

We can so using `unlink` in php

But if you want to do it the Laravel way, use the File::delete() method instead.

// Delete a single file

```
use File;
File::delete($filename);
```

// Delete multiple files

```
File::delete($file1, $file2, $file3);
```

// Delete an array of files

```
$files = array($file1, $file2);
File::delete($files);
```

Note: $filename contain full path and image name like ['https://www.example.com/images/image.jpg']

Answer (score -1):

you can use unlink for removing previous image file if exists by this code:

```
if($request->hasFile('file')){
    if(file_exists(public_path("your image url"))){
        unlink(public_path("your image url"));
    };
    UploadImage($request)
}
```

and UploadImage() define as:

```
private function UploadImage($request){
    $file = $request->file('file');
    $name = time() . $file->getClientOriginalName();
    $file->move('uploads/images', $name);
    $employee->file = $name;
    $employee->save();
}
```

Comment: your answer works but if that image already exist in databse than it will unlink,
i want that during add employee time the image I upload it will replace that.\

Comment: you can try it now, if image exist before unlink it and then upload.